# Visualforce Email Template issue with Case Owner values

Tags: visualforce, email-template

Two questions. I have an Email template for Case object. Basically I was able to add many fields in the case object itself using `{!relatedTo.casefieldname}`format. Now I need to add some case owner information like owner name, role etc... But when I add user role like,

```
{!relatedTo.Owner.UserRole}
```

it keep showing me an ID only, not an exact value. Not sure how can I achieve this?

Next question is i also need to add an URL within the template itself. So I hard coded the URL. But when we generate the email, the hard coded url is scrambled. So any best practices to hard code URL?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to direct access the case owner name, role for that you have query, please find the solution below : -

1. your email template is correct, just use component like below : -

Apex component :

```
<apex:component controller="findSmithAccounts" access="global">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!SmithAccounts}" var="s_account">
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
            {!s_account.Name}
        </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:component>
```

2. Query your owner Name and role in the controller like below : -

   SELECT Name,UserRoleId
   FROM User 
   WHERE Id IN (SELECT OwnerId 
                FROM Case
                WHERE Case.CaseNumber = '00001234')
3. use the component in the email template.

Comment: Thanks, what about the second question, the hard coded URL?

Comment: @L Mudiyanse, if it working then accept and upvote the answer so that other can found it useful.

Comment: "hard coded URL" i didn't get you ??